# Chrome Android instantaneous button feedback

Tags: css, button, user-experience, mobile-webkit

I am creating a simple mobile app with Cordova. For good user experience I would like there to be instant feedback whenever a user presses a button. This should be accomplished with the `:active` pseudoclass. It mostly works, but it's not quite 'instant'.

See the [jsbin here](http://output.jsbin.com/baxuqe).

- With desktop Chrome, clicking the button produces absolutely instant feedback, no question.
- With Chrome for Android, tapping the button quickly feels pretty quick, but a slow tap or holding on the button causes a delay (it might be hard to notice, but it is there and it's bugging me).

I think this is something to do with scrolling. If you go to the Android settings, there is a scrolling list of options. These options seem to highlight with a similar delay. However, any native Android buttons which are not within a scrolling list are absolutely instant (for example, the back button in the top right, or save/cancel on a popup dialog).

Is there some way I can convince Chrome that these buttons are not on any kind of scrolling pane and should just be highlighted instantly?

This is probably unrelated, but I have also noticed that holding on an html button highlights it, but then moving your finger (still within the button) causes the highlight to disappear. This does not match the behaviour of native Android buttons, which would stay highlighted so long as you stay within the button.

Edit: I should add that `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` (which only works with `cursor: pointer`) is a bit faster than `:active`, but it's not an acceptable solution, for a few reasons:

1. The highlight disappears if you hold on the button for more than one second
2. It clashes with `:active` - to get sensible results with `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` you would have to remove `:active`, which makes no sense
3. There is no way to control the size/shape of the highlight, which might not match the actual button (sometimes it bleeds around the edge, or has mismatching rounded corners)

The correct HTML way of solving this is `:active`, and I would like to use that if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way to solve this is to listen for touch events and set a class:

```
$('button').on('touchstart', function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('button').on('touchend', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

To keep this as closely related to the `:active` pseudoclass, I opted to use a class of `active` and add styles for both like this:

```
button:active, button.active {
    // active style
}
```

For more information, see: http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/alternative-to-webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-phonegap-apps/